# Regular Expression for formatting numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, formatting

I need to display a formatted number on a web page using JavaScript. I want to format it so that there are commas in the right places. How would I do this with a regular expression? I've gotten as far as something like this:

```
myString = myString.replace(/^(\d{3})*$/g, "${1},");
```

...and then realized this would be more complex than I think (and the regex above is **not even close** to what I need). I've done some searching and I'm having a hard time finding something that works for this.

Basically, I want these results:

- 45 becomes 45
- 3856 becomes 3,856
- 398868483992 becomes 398,868,483,992

...you get the idea.

Comment: Most people have shown approaches that require iteration but there are fixed forms as well.

Comment: If this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/150034), see [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

This can be done in a single regex, no iteration required. If your browser supports ECMAScript 2018, you could simply use lookaround and just insert commas at the right places:

Search for `(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))` and replace all with `,`

In older versions, JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind, so that doesn't work. Fortunately, we only need to change a little bit:

Search for `(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))` and replace all with `\1,`

So, in JavaScript, that would look like:

```
result = subject.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
```

Explanation: Assert that from the current position in the string onwards, it is possible to match digits in multiples of three, and that there is a digit left of the current position.

This will also work with decimals (123456.78) as long as there aren't too many digits "to the right of the dot" (otherwise you get 123,456.789,012).

You can also define it in a Number prototype, as follows:

```
Number.prototype.format = function(){
   return this.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
};
```

And then using it like this:

```
var num = 1234;
alert(num.format());
```

Credit: Jeffrey Friedl, [Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd. edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126/), p. 66-67

Comment: This is brilliant, except when you get into floats: `0.1523234 -> 0.1,523,234`

Comment: Forgot to add...if you do expect floats smaller than 1, then add a condition to require that the number is larger than 999 before doing the replacement (it's better than trying to come up with a more complex RegExp to account for floats smaller than 1 that could end up being very inefficient).

Comment: @10basetom: I did mention this limitation at the end of my answer; also, adding that condition won't help - `1000.123456` would still be butchered :)

Comment: I know this is old but `result = subject.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");` didn't work for me.  I had to add `toString()` as in your prototype example.

Comment: Just curious here. I think the above expression will convert everything in decimal numbers as well. I mean we will get something like this -  123,456.123,456 .

Comment: @malhar: Yes, I explained that in my answer.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - My bad. I was kind of curious how could we achieve that.  can we use negative look-behind and positive look-behind `(?<!\d)`at the same time, it does not seem to be working. Same with Positive look-ahead  .something like `(?=\.)` in addition to the existing regex.

Comment: does it work for decimal don't want for decimal to show, have four place decimal

Answer (score 22):

Formatting a number can be handled elegantly with one line of code.

This code extends the Number object; usage examples are included below.

**Code:**

```
Number.prototype.format = function () {
    return this.toString().split( /(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g ).join( "," );
};
```

**How it works**

The regular expression uses a look-ahead to find positions within the string where the only thing to the right of it is one or more groupings of three numbers, until either a decimal or the end of string is encountered.  The `.split()` is used to break the string at those points into array elements, and then the `.join()` merges those elements back into a string, separated by commas.

The concept of finding **positions** within the string, rather than matching actual characters, is important in order to split the string without removing any characters.

**Usage examples:**

```
var n = 9817236578964235;
alert( n.format() );    // Displays "9,817,236,578,964,235"

n = 87345.87;
alert( n.format() );    // Displays "87,345.87"
```

Of course, the code can easily be extended or changed to handle locale considerations.  For example, here is a new version of the code that automatically detects the locale settings and swaps the use of commas and periods.

**Locale-aware version:**

```
Number.prototype.format = function () {

    if ((1.1).toLocaleString().indexOf(".") >= 0) {
        return this.toString().split( /(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g ).join( "," );
    }
    else {
        return this.toString().split( /(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:,|$))/g ).join( "." );
    }
};
```

Unless it's really necessary, I prefer the simplicity of the first version though.

Comment: that perfect work for me also work this regex: `replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");`

Comment: It is not good practice to extend native objects in JavaScript. When you extend an object, you modify its behavior. Its better to just write it as a simple function or to define your own class which won't cause unexpected behavior with the original object.

Comment: Well, that's a philosophical and debatable argument. The good news is that you can easily take the code in my answer above and create a simple function, as you said you prefer.

Comment: Like the other answers, this only works for integers. Your decimal example doesn't have enough digits to show that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

With the caveat that `Intl.NumberFormat` and `Number.toLocaleString()` are now there for this purpose in JavaScript:

The other answers using regular expressions all break down for decimal numbers (although the authors seem to not know this because they have only tested with 1 or 2 decimal places). This is because without lookbehind, JS regular expressions have no way to know whether you are working with the block of digits before or after the decimal point. That leaves two ways to address this with JS regular expressions:

1. Know whether there is a decimal point in the number, and use different regular expressions depending on that:

   - `/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g` for integers
   - `/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g` for decimals
2. Use two regular expressions, one to match the decimal portion, and a second to do a replace on it.

```js
function format(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/^[+-]?\d+/, function(int) {
    return int.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
  });
}

console.log(format(332432432))
console.log(format(332432432.3432432))
console.log(format(-332432432))
console.log(format(1E6))
console.log(format(1E-6))
```

Comment: This is probably the best method if you don't have look behind support. When used for masking an input field you can run a first pass with a regex to insert your decimal at the desired number of places, then run the result through this method and you get perfect comma distribution without hosing up your decimals.

Answer (score 6):

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
var num=numberWithCommas(2000000); //any number
console.log(num);

enter code here
```

Try this

Answer (score 4):

// You might want to take decimals into account

```
Number.prototype.commas= function(){
 var s= '', temp, 
 num= this.toString().split('.'), n=num[0];
 while(n.length> 3){
  temp= n.substring(n.length-3);
  s= ','+temp+s;
  n= n.slice(0, -3);
 }
 if(n) s= n+s;
 if(num[1]) s+='.'+num[1];
 return s;
}
```

var n=  10000000000.34;

n.commas() = returned value: (String) 10,000,000,000.34

Comment: This very large function is a great example of why we have regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

[underscore.string](https://github.com/esamattis/underscore.string) has [a nice implementation](https://github.com/esamattis/underscore.string/blob/master/numberFormat.js).

I've amended it slightly to accept numeric strings.

```js
function numberFormat(number, dec, dsep, tsep) {
  if (isNaN(number) || number == null) return '';

  number = parseFloat(number).toFixed(~~dec);
  tsep = typeof tsep == 'string' ? tsep : ',';

  var parts = number.split('.'),
    fnums = parts[0],
    decimals = parts[1] ? (dsep || '.') + parts[1] : '';

  return fnums.replace(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g, '$1' + tsep) + decimals;
}

console.log(numberFormat(123456789))
console.log(numberFormat(123456789.123456789))
console.log(numberFormat(-123456789))
console.log(numberFormat(1E6))
console.log(numberFormat(1E-6))
console.log('---')
console.log(numberFormat(123456789, 6, ',', '_'))
console.log(numberFormat(123456789.123456789, 6, ',', '_'))
console.log(numberFormat(-123456789, 6, ',', '_'))
console.log(numberFormat(1E6, 6, ',', '_'))
console.log(numberFormat(1E-6, 6, ',', '_'))
```

Answer (score 2):

One RegExp for integers and decimals:

```
// Formats number 1234.5678 into string "1 234.5678".
function formatNumber(number: number): string {
    return number.toString().replace(/(?<!(\.\d*|^.{0}))(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ');
}

console.log(formatNumber(1234.5678)); // "1 234.5678"
console.log(formatNumber(123)); // "123"
console.log(formatNumber(123.45678)); // "123.45678"
console.log(formatNumber(123456789.11111111)); // "123 456 789.1111111"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function add_commas(numStr)
{
    numStr += '';
    var x = numStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a regex, you can use two in a while loop:

```
while(num.match(/\d{4}/)) {
    num = num.replace(/(\d{3})(,\d|$)/, ',$1$2');
}
```

And if you want to be fancy, you can format numbers with decimal points too:

```
while(num.match(/\d{4}(\,|\.)/)) {
    num = num.replace(/(\d{3})(,\d|$|\.)/, ',$1$2');
}
```

**Edit:**

You can also do this with 2 regular expressions and no loop, splits, joins, etc:

```
num = num.replace(/(\d{1,2}?)((\d{3})+)$/, "$1,$2");
num = num.replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1,");
```

The first regex puts a comma after the first 1 or 2 digits if the remaining number of digits is divisible by three.  The second regex places a comma after every remaining group of 3 digits.

These won't work with decimals, but they work great for positive and negative integers.

**Test output:**

```
45
3,856
398,868,483,992

635
12,358,717,859,918,856
-1,388,488,184
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone mentioned that lookbehind isn't possible in Javascript RegExp. Here is a great page that explains how to use lookaround (lookahead and lookbehind).

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you would necessarily have to do multiple passes to achieve this with regular expressions. Try the following:

1. Run a regex for one digit followed by 3 digits.
2. If that regex matches, replace it with the first digit, then a comma, then the next 3 digits.
3. Repeat until (1) finds no matches.

Answer (score 0):

First reverse a character array, then add commas after every third number unless it's just before the end of the string or before a - sign. Then reverse the character array again and make it a string again.

```
function add_commas(numStr){
    return numStr.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(\d{3})(?=[^$|^-])/g, "$1,").split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it...almost.  See my answer for the part you missed.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration isn't necessary

```
function formatNumber(n, separator) {
    separator = separator || ",";

    n = n.toString()
        .split("").reverse().join("")
        .replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1" + separator)
        .split("").reverse().join("");

    // Strings that have a length that is a multiple of 3 will have a leading separator
    return n[0] == separator ? n.substr(1) : n;
}

var testCases = [1, 45, 2856, 398868483992];
for ( var i in testCases ) {
    if ( !ns.hasOwnProperty(i) ) { continue; }
    console.info(testCases[i]);   
    console.log(formatNumber(testCases[i]));
}
```

Results

```
1
1

45
45

2856
2,856

398868483992
398,868,483,992
```

Answer (score 0):

Brandon,

I didn't see too many answers working the regex from the decimal point back, so I thought I might chime in.

I wondered if there is any elegant benefit to re-writing the regexp to scan from the back forward...

```
function addCommas(inputText) {
    // pattern works from right to left
    var commaPattern = /(\d+)(\d{3})(\.\d*)*$/;
    var callback = function (match, p1, p2, p3) {
        return p1.replace(commaPattern, callback) + ',' + p2 + (p3 || '');
    };
    return inputText.replace(commaPattern, callback);
}
```

[**>> Fiddle Demo <<**](http://jsfiddle.net/L5hgk/)

This accounts for any decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

After so much searching, I generate a regex which accepts all formats

(\d+[-, ,(]{0,3}\d+[-, ,(,)]{0,3}\d+[-, ,(,)]{0,3}\d+[)]{0,2})