# How to format a number with commas as thousands separators?

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers

I am trying to print an integer in JavaScript with commas as thousands separators. For example, I want to show the number 1234567 as "1,234,567". How would I go about doing this?

Here is how I am doing it:

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    x = x.toString();
    var pattern = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (pattern.test(x))
        x = x.replace(pattern, "$1,$2");
    return x;
}

console.log(numberWithCommas(1000))
```

Is there a simpler or more elegant way to do it? It would be nice if it works with floats also, but that is not necessary. It does not need to be locale-specific to decide between periods and commas.

Comment: toLocaleString is inconsistent and should not be used. For example - on Firefox this will return 1,234 but on IE this will add decimals: 1,234.00

Comment: As of 2023, `toLocaleString` appears to work fine on Safari, and I'm seeing consistent results between Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Answer (score 3882, accepted):

I used the idea from Kerry's answer, but simplified it since I was just looking for something simple for my specific purpose. Here is what I have:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function test(x, expect) {
    const result = numberWithCommas(x);
    const pass = result === expect;
    console.log(`${pass ? "✓" : "ERROR ====>"} ${x} => ${result}`);
    return pass;
}

let failures = 0;
failures += !test(0,        "0");
failures += !test(100,      "100");
failures += !test(1000,     "1,000");
failures += !test(10000,    "10,000");
failures += !test(100000,   "100,000");
failures += !test(1000000,  "1,000,000");
failures += !test(10000000, "10,000,000");
if (failures) {
    console.log(`${failures} test(s) failed`);
} else {
    console.log("All tests passed");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

The regex uses 2 lookahead assertions:

- a positive one to look for any point in the string that has a multiple of 3 digits in a row after it,
- a negative assertion to make sure that point only has exactly a multiple of 3 digits. The replacement expression puts a comma there.

For example, if you pass it `123456789.01`, the positive assertion will match every spot to the left of the 7 (since `789` is a multiple of 3 digits, `678` is a multiple of 3 digits, `567`, etc.). The negative assertion checks that the multiple of 3 digits does not have any digits after it. `789` has a period after it so it is exactly a multiple of 3 digits, so a comma goes there. `678` is a multiple of 3 digits but it has a `9` after it, so those 3 digits are part of a group of 4, and a comma does not go there. Similarly for `567`. `456789` is 6 digits, which is a multiple of 3, so a comma goes before that. `345678` is a multiple of 3, but it has a `9` after it, so no comma goes there. And so on. The `\B` keeps the regex from putting a comma at the beginning of the string.

@[neu-rah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329075/neu-rah) mentioned that this function adds commas in undesirable places if there are more than 3 digits after the decimal point. If this is a problem, you can use this function:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}
```

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}

function test(x, expect) {
    const result = numberWithCommas(x);
    const pass = result === expect;
    console.log(`${pass ? "✓" : "ERROR ====>"} ${x} => ${result}`);
    return pass;
}

let failures = 0;
failures += !test(0              , "0");
failures += !test(0.123456       , "0.123456");
failures += !test(100            , "100");
failures += !test(100.123456     , "100.123456");
failures += !test(1000           , "1,000");
failures += !test(1000.123456    , "1,000.123456");
failures += !test(10000          , "10,000");
failures += !test(10000.123456   , "10,000.123456");
failures += !test(100000         , "100,000");
failures += !test(100000.123456  , "100,000.123456");
failures += !test(1000000        , "1,000,000");
failures += !test(1000000.123456 , "1,000,000.123456");
failures += !test(10000000       , "10,000,000");
failures += !test(10000000.123456, "10,000,000.123456");
if (failures) {
    console.log(`${failures} test(s) failed`);
} else {
    console.log("All tests passed");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

@[t.j.crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) pointed out that now that JavaScript has lookbehind ([support info](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind)), it can be solved in the regular expression itself:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function test(x, expect) {
    const result = numberWithCommas(x);
    const pass = result === expect;
    console.log(`${pass ? "✓" : "ERROR ====>"} ${x} => ${result}`);
    return pass;
}

let failures = 0;
failures += !test(0,               "0");
failures += !test(0.123456,        "0.123456");
failures += !test(100,             "100");
failures += !test(100.123456,      "100.123456");
failures += !test(1000,            "1,000");
failures += !test(1000.123456,     "1,000.123456");
failures += !test(10000,           "10,000");
failures += !test(10000.123456,    "10,000.123456");
failures += !test(100000,          "100,000");
failures += !test(100000.123456,   "100,000.123456");
failures += !test(1000000,         "1,000,000");
failures += !test(1000000.123456,  "1,000,000.123456");
failures += !test(10000000,        "10,000,000");
failures += !test(10000000.123456, "10,000,000.123456");
if (failures) {
    console.log(`${failures} test(s) failed`);
} else {
    console.log("All tests passed");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

`(?<!\.\d*)` is a negative lookbehind that says the match can't be preceded by a `.` followed by zero or more digits. The negative lookbehind is faster than the `split` and `join` solution ([comparison](http://jsben.ch/umq99)), at least in V8.

Comment: Very cool, did notice that it has problems with numbers that have more than 3 places after the decimal point though.

Comment: try numberWithCommas(12345.6789) -> "12,345.6,789" i dont like it

Comment: It doesn't work well with fractions, we wouldn't want to have commas after the decimal point

Comment: Small improvement that fix after '.' problem

'123456789.01234'.replace(/\B(?=(?=\d*\.)(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '_')

Comment: What a beautiful solution. A simple and nice addon is the seperator as a second argument, as numbers aren't seperated by commas in every language.

Comment: Intl.NumberFormat() seems a little more up-to-date since it uses locale doodads.

Comment: Appending a null string rather than calling .toString() is generally a bit faster, so you can __return (x+'').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');__

Also doesn't throw a JS error if you pass it null or undefined, but typecasting does mean you turn __undefined__ into the string 'undefined' etc. which is something to be aware of.

Comment: was going to do a quick jsfiddle of append vs .toString() but somebody else got there first! if you're curious http://jsperf.com/tostring-vs-appending-empty-string/3

Comment: If you change the first line to var `var parts = (x) ? (x+"").split(".") : [""];`, then you can pass this as a map function over an array of values like so `[1000].map(numberWithCommas)`.

Comment: @hypno7oad, my function seems to work fine with `map` the way it is now. Your change just seems to make it behave strangely when 0 is passed.

Comment: @EliasZamaria I was trying to handle undefined or null values, since the current function throws errors when it receives them. This could be important when working with datasets that include them, which is how I stumbled upon this thread. BTW, thanks for the answer. It helped me out with my current task. However, you're right that my addition breaks down when it encounters 0. For the sake of brevity, I tried to rely solely on the 'truthiness' of x, which obviously was wrong since 0 is falsy. Try this instead `var parts = (x || x === 0) ? (x+"").split(".") : [""];`

Comment: I improved this to also handle exponential notation and thought I'd share it:     var parts = x.toString().split(".");
  var e = false;
  if (parts.length == 1) {
   parts = x.toString().split("E");
   e = true;
  }
     parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
     return (e ? parts.join("E") : parts.join("."));

Comment: This is fine but it's specific to countries that use commas as thousand separators (many use periods). Take a look at @ukolka's solution, which uses the builtin function toLocaleString() and auto-converts a number based on the locale.

Comment: @DmitrijGolubev Doesn't work for integers. Perhaps forcing the decimal point would be the solution.

Comment: @DmitrijGolubev: Your solution works for the number `42`, but fails for the number `2398512`. Any idea why?

Comment: This [website, regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cM9mE7/2) explains regex expressions. Might help.

Comment: If you add x = parseFloat(x).toFixed(2) then you can ensure there's never more than 3 digits after the decimal point

Comment: Downvoted because answer should just be Number(n).toLocaleString()

Comment: @yar1 what if you are planning on using that in Safari? Then you just get the number back with no commas.

Comment: If you add zero decimal e.g. 0.30000000004 it returns 0.30,000,000,004

Comment: @David, did you read my whole answer, including the part where I mention neu-rah's observation that it inserts commas in undesirable places, and my fix for that?

Comment: @EliasZamaria I don't understand why you didn't incorporate neu-rah's solution, but rather offer it as an improvement? I'd understand if that solution involved more than a few lines of code.

Comment: hi guys , i implement this for textbox and i can only enter 5 digit , any specific reason? Not good with regex. (not saying this is wrong, just need clue ) Thanks

Comment: the answer num.toLocaleString() below is more correct, because it is built-in and because it accounts for cultural differences. Europe uses commas in numbers differently from the US

Comment: The parenthesis in `(x)` is not necessary. If only one variable is present `x` will suffice.

Comment: This piece of JS is awesome. It's better than using `toLocaleString()` because `toLocaleString()` does not affect on the numbers placed in another string. `(eg: The value is greater than 15000 but ...)` but this piece of code does. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work...
Consider... 
9429700000
With this code you get
9,429,700,0000

Comment: @codingguy3000 The function posted at the end of the answer does not have this problem.

Comment: Now that JavaScript is getting lookbehind, the digits-after-the-decimal part can be solved in the regex rather than using `split` and `join`: `.replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")`. I've updated the answer to show that as well. Being a variable length lookbehind I worried about performance, but it [beats `split` and `join`](http://jsben.ch/umq99).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's breaking in Safari ```Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name```

Comment: @JuniusL. - See the [support info](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) linked in the answer.

Comment: Not a good solution! Use `toLocaleString()` and stop being North American focused. UGH.

Comment: be careful with this code. it doesn't work in firefox

Comment: Doesnt work with numbers that have long decimal values (just tested with four : ie : 12223.0234)

Comment: @hendr1x what is the problem? This answer mentions that the first snippet puts commas in undesirable places if there are more than 3 digits after the decimal point. The 2nd and 3rd work fine, and return "12,223.0234".

Comment: to have two decimals: `x.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");`

Comment: This does not work in safari. Broke my entire application and took me forever to figure out this was the problem

Comment: Doesn't work in IE11!
It has an issue with the regEx for some reason: "Unexpected quantifier"

Comment: @EliasZamaria please edit you answer about lookbehind
It can't be used in enterprise still. The latest Safari doesn't support it.
And it can't be polyfilled.
Many guys above broke their apps because of that suggestion as well as one from my team.
Please add that it is not yet ready to use like with uppercase characters.

Comment: @DzmitryVasilevsky I didn't add the lookbehind stuff to this answer. I can remove it, but I think it is useful, and this answer still has my original solution, for interpreters that don't support lookbehind.

Comment: @EliasZamaria The fact is that it is causing problems for seekers.
I don't think this should be removed but rather edited like:
t.j.crowder pointed out that there is a cutting edge way to solve that. Be aware that it is STILL NOT SUPPORTED by some of the modern browsers - support info)!
Modern JavaScript has lookbehind, it can be solved in the regular expression itself...

Comment: @DzmitryVasilevsky is the "support info" link that is there now good enough? Or does it need to be made more obvious and noticeable?

Comment: @EliasZamaria I think should be more noticeable.
BTW thanks for cooperation

Comment: I think adding a link to `toLocaleString`, [uKolka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17663871/1075247)'s answer or explaining why this might be better than that function would be good.

Comment: This solution DOES NOT work for safari and iphone chrome. It will break your entire application and it's hard to debug in mobile. Please consider down-voting this solution to save people's time.

Comment: The answer is good for some browsers, but since it doesn't work in Safari on Mac/iOS (as of June 2022), it should not be the top accepted answer. A big obvious note should be added to say that it shouldn't be used in a production environment.

Comment: None of these work with the number 57024.00000000001

Comment: @Cybernetic I just ran `(57024.00000000001).toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")` and got `57,024.00000000001`.

Comment: @EliasZamaria interesting....I get `57,024.00,000,000,001` .... I am on Chrome Version 102.0.5005.115 (Official Build) (arm64)

Comment: @Cybernetic are you sure you are using one of the last 2 `numberWithCommas` functions in this answer (not the first)?

Comment: @EliasZamaria you're correct, my apologies. I was using (x).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

Comment: Split is slow. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/woqfgvs3/ (uses indexOf)

Comment: This doesn't work in any IOS browser, be warned!!

Comment: This was the same ChatGPTs answer return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

Comment: For decimal numbers, you an split the number by the decimal separator and just AddThousandSeparator to the number part. Then concatenate decimal part with decimal part. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 3138):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned [Number.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).
It's implemented in JavaScript 1.5 (which was introduced in 1999) so it's basically supported across all major browsers.

```js
var n = 34523453.345;
console.log(n.toLocaleString());    // "34,523,453.345"
```

It also works in Node.js as of v0.12 via inclusion of [Intl](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js)

If you want something different, [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) might be interesting.

Comment: I upvoted, but upon further research found some problems with this answer.  The performance is not as good as a regex formatter.  See the following link: http://jsperf.com/number-formatting-with-commas.  

Also trying to get trailing zeros as decimal places is problematic.

Comment: @csigrist Good points, but it's not as bad as it seems. Speed is browser dependent. In FF or Opera it performs good. I sucks in Chrome though. As for zeroes:
`var number = 123456.000;
number.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
"123,456.00"`
Those options don't work in FF or Safari though.

Comment: The performance difference may or may not be an issue, depending on the context.  If used for a giant table of 1000 results then it will be more important but if only used for a single value, the difference is negligible.  But the advantage is that it's locale-aware, so someone in Europe would see _34.523.453,345_ or _34 523 453,345_.  This would be more important on a site with visitors from many countries.

Comment: Awesome. Finally an answer with native function. And what more, this one displays properly in different countries with different separators (in Czech Republic we write `X XXX XXX,YYY`).

Comment: For `var n = 12345.54321` Chrome prints `12,345.543` without 2 decimals.

Comment: @curiosu please read the docs and previous comments.
`var number = 12345.54321; number.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 10});`

Comment: toLocaleString() has poor mobile support, better to use your own javascript function for now

Comment: The OP was asking for a coma separator.  As many languages doesn't use coma as thousands separator, you may want to use a specific language that has a coma separator: `toLocaleString('en')`

Comment: Update for googlers: `toLocaleString` works in Node.js as of v0.12 via the [inclusion of Intl](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/pull/7719).

Comment: Hmm. Can't get it to work in Chrome 48 console. I type:"1234567".toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}); and get "1234567".

Comment: @MSC you should try `parseInt("1234567", 10).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2})` or `new Number("1234567").toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2})` instead. It doesn't work because you use it on a string, not a number.

Comment: Also `number.toLocaleString` does not work in PhantomJS. [Number.toLocaleString() doesn't apply appropriate formatting](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12581)

Comment: @jcollum Could you specify which version of Node you're referring to? I'm working with v4.4.7 and it's works perfectly.

Comment: As of this comment, `.toLocaleString()` doesn't appear to work in the latest version of Chrome (v60.0).

Comment: @A-Diddy just tried this in Chrtome 61 and it works fine

Comment: Skuld & all, wth... I just confirmed that you're correct, `.toLocalString()` appears to now work as described above in Chrome v61. How weird that v61 comes out with support minutes after I posted that comment. Talk about Big Brother... Google engineers are on it.

Comment: If the intention is displaying 123456.789 as "١٢٣٬٤٥٦٫٧٨٩" when language code is "ar", "၁၂၃,၄၅၆.၇၈၉" for language code "my", then using `.toLocaleString()'. However, if you just want to insert thousand separating commas, then you will want to use Devin G Rhode's solution.

Comment: Not a good option if you're a functional programmer because it does not work with literal number objects, just variables.

Comment: @mmla By option you mean JavaScript? It's a mixed-paradigm language. This does work on literals, maybe not in ways you're expecting. Try `(123123).toLocaleString()`

Comment: Note. this won't work with Android if you are developing React Native app.

Comment: **Note:** You may need to cast your number string to an int or float first, i.e. `parseInt(123456, 10).toLocaleString()` or `parseFloat(123456.789012, 10).toLocaleString()`. Also, in the latter case, `.toLocaleString()` will by default limit the number of decimal digits.

Comment: Take your Like~!!

Comment: **Keep in mind that `toLocaleString` is implementation specific - you will get different results across browsers/environments.**

Comment: If you want to get the format corresponding to the language of the page, you can do `toLocaleString(document.documentElement.lang)`.

Answer (score 558):

Below are two different browser APIs that can transform *Numbers* into structured *Strings*. Keep in mind that not all users' machines have a [**locale** that uses commas in numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator). To enforce commas to the output, any "western" *locale* may be used, such as `en-US`

```
let number = 1234567890; // Example number to be converted
```

⚠️ Mind that javascript has a [maximum integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) value of `9007199254740991`

---

### [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```
// default behaviour on a machine with a locale that uses commas for numbers
let number = 1234567890;
number.toLocaleString(); // "1,234,567,890"

// With custom settings, forcing a "US" locale to guarantee commas in output
let number2 = 1234.56789; // floating point example
number2.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits:2}); // "1,234.57"

//You can also force a minimum of 2 trailing digits
let number3 = 1.5;
number3.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2}); //"1.50"
```

### [NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

```
let number = 1234567890;
let nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US');
nf.format(number); // "1,234,567,890"
```

---

From what I checked (Firefox at least) they are both more or less same regarding performance.

⚡ **Live demo**: https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/MWjdbgL?editors=1000

Comment: Browsers support is always mentioned at the bottom of each MDN page, which I've linked to.

Comment: basic `toLocaleString` works on safari, options don't

Comment: As others have noted, `number.toLocaleString` does not work for all browsers, nor in PhantomJS. [Number.toLocaleString() doesn't apply appropriate formatting](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12581)

Comment: the `toLocaleString` solution should probably also include the desired locale, so `toLocaleString("en")`, because the English pattern uses commas. However, if `toLocaleString()` without locale indicator is run in France, then it'll yield periods instead of commas because that's what is used to separate thousands locally.

Comment: `minimumFractionDigits: 2` can also be added to ensure a fixed number of decimal places https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581011/how-to-use-tolocalestring-and-tofixed2-in-javascript#31581206

Comment: While `9007199254740991` is the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` you can use `toLocaleString()` up to `Number.MAX_VALUE` which is `1.7976931348623157e+308`. Anything larger than this will return `∞`.

Comment: Saved my time and `toLocaleString` is useful and works on FireFox and Chrome very good.

Comment: tnx brother.. var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat();
nf.format(number); // "1,234,567,890" it's work

Comment: Instead of `'en-US'`, you could use `navigator.userLanguage`. [Legacy browser support.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61196133/819417)

Answer (score 124):

I suggest using phpjs.org 's [number_format()](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301100122/http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/)

```
function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number, 
        prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
        sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
        dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
        toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
            // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
            var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
            return Math.round(n * k) / k;
        },
        s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : Math.round(n)).toString().split('.');
    if (s[0].length > 3) {
        s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
    }
    if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
        s[1] = s[1] || '';
        s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
    }
    return s.join(dec);
}
```

---

**UPDATE 02/13/14**

People have been reporting this doesn't work as expected, so I did a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/xc3qh35z/) that includes automated tests.

**Update 26/11/2017**

Here's that fiddle as a Stack Snippet with slightly modified output:

```js
function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number, 
        prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
        sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
        dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
        toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
            // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
            var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
            return Math.round(n * k) / k;
        },
        s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : Math.round(n)).toString().split('.');
    if (s[0].length > 3) {
        s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
    }
    if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
        s[1] = s[1] || '';
        s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
    }
    return s.join(dec);
}

var exampleNumber = 1;
function test(expected, number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep)
{
    var actual = number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep);
    console.log(
        'Test case ' + exampleNumber + ': ' +
        '(decimals: ' + (typeof decimals === 'undefined' ? '(default)' : decimals) +
        ', dec_point: "' + (typeof dec_point === 'undefined' ? '(default)' : dec_point) + '"' +
        ', thousands_sep: "' + (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined' ? '(default)' : thousands_sep) + '")'
    );
    console.log('  => ' + (actual === expected ? 'Passed' : 'FAILED') + ', got "' + actual + '", expected "' + expected + '".');
    exampleNumber++;
}

test('1,235',    1234.56);
test('1 234,56', 1234.56, 2, ',', ' ');
test('1234.57',  1234.5678, 2, '.', '');
test('67,00',    67, 2, ',', '.');
test('1,000',    1000);
test('67.31',    67.311, 2);
test('1,000.6',  1000.55, 1);
test('67.000,00000', 67000, 5, ',', '.');
test('1',        0.9, 0);
test('1.20',     '1.20', 2);
test('1.2000',   '1.20', 4);
test('1.200',    '1.2000', 3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Not that I marked it down, but I believe people did so because it does not work. As it stands I find even some of your tests to not work.

Comment: @Andrew S -- Only 1 person has marked it down. It does work, I have used it in my own code many times. It's also not my code (nor my tests), I referenced the site that it comes from, which is a well-known site. Perhaps they have an updated version of it) as the code you are looking at is 3 years old.

Comment: @ernix - The operator asked for JavaScript, that answer I gave *is* JavaScript. This is a JavaScript interpretation of a PHP function.

Comment: @Kerry, this `number_format('str')` returns '0'.  I think it's far from interpretation.

Comment: @ernix - it works exactly as expected with the example the OP gave. I put a fiddle so you can see.

Comment: @ernix - Okay, but the point is that it does *exactly* what the OP asked for. It is from another site (not maintained by me, and I've stated this previously), and when giving it proper variables, it works exactly as stated. If you believe that to be a bug, contact phpjs.org or see if they have an updated version.

Comment: I've updated this since JavaScript's parseFloat stops at the first comma it sees, so if you passed in a string with commas, it would not see the entire string as a number... http://jsfiddle.net/xc3qh35z/63/ and I needed a function that could handle the text values from HTML input elements, which will often already have commas and decimal points in them.  The modification removes ALL non-numeric characters except decimal points before generating the new string, so it should handle US numbers other than currency out of the box.

Comment: This one is perfect except for one issue.  It would be better if there was an extra, optional argument for rounding vs. truncating.  Rounding isn't always the desired approach.

Comment: This is perfect. I kept looking and only finding incredibly bloated libraries that didn't even let me change thousands and decimal separator.

Answer (score 84):

This is a variation of @mikez302's answer, but modified to support numbers with decimals (per @neu-rah's feedback that numberWithCommas(12345.6789) -> "12,345.6,789" instead of "12,345.6789"

```
function numberWithCommas(n) {
    var parts=n.toString().split(".");
    return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
}
```

Comment: Hey look, [you're an open-source contributor](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/132e795daffdb866baa41a84079224772eaa0c24/addons/src/createNumberMask.js#L144) :)

Answer (score 81):

```
function formatNumber (num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
}

print(formatNumber(2665));      // 2,665
print(formatNumber(102665));    // 102,665
print(formatNumber(111102665)); // 111,102,665
```

Comment: What does this do that my answer doesn't? The regex looks slightly different but it looks like it should do the same thing.

Comment: This is elegant. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: From http://blog.tompawlak.org/number-currency-formatting-javascript?
Known issue: formatNumber(0.123456) = 0.123,456
The absence of lookbehind in JS makes it difficult to fix it with an elegant regex.

Comment: this allows characters like abcdef and so on.. which should be restricted.

Comment: 123456789.123456789.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,') => 123,456,789.12345679

Comment: This was my favorite of the solutions.

Comment: This doesn't work in older safari (2022 Safari on iOS for example in iOS 16.1.1)

Answer (score 75):

**Using Regular expression**

```
function toCommas(value) {
    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
console.log(toCommas(123456789)); // 123,456,789

console.log(toCommas(1234567890)); // 1,234,567,890
console.log(toCommas(1234)); // 1,234
```

**Using toLocaleString()**

```
var number = 123456.789;

// request a currency format
console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }));
// → 123.456,79 €

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(number.toLocaleString('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }))
// → ￥123,457

// limit to three significant digits
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }));
// → 1,23,000
```

ref [MDN:Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

**Using Intl.NumberFormat()**

```
var number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// expected output: "123.456,79 €"

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }).format(number));
// expected output: "￥123,457"

// limit to three significant digits
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(number));

// expected output: "1,23,000"
```

ref [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

**DEMO AT HERE**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Using Regular expression
  function toCommas(value) {
    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }

  function commas() {
    var num1 = document.myform.number1.value;

    // Using Regular expression
    document.getElementById('result1').value = toCommas(parseInt(num1));
    // Using toLocaleString()

    document.getElementById('result2').value = parseInt(num1).toLocaleString('ja-JP', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'JPY'
    });

    // Using Intl.NumberFormat()
    document.getElementById('result3').value = new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'JPY'
    }).format(num1);
  }
</script>
<FORM NAME="myform">
  <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="number1" VALUE="123456789">
  <br>
  <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="=>" onClick="commas()">
  <br>Using Regular expression
  <br>
  <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="result1" NAME="result1" VALUE="">
  <br>Using toLocaleString()
  <br>
  <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="result2" NAME="result2" VALUE="">
  <br>Using Intl.NumberFormat()
  <br>
  <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="result3" NAME="result3" VALUE="">

</FORM>
```

**Performance**

[image: Performance]
http://jsben.ch/sifRd

Comment: This doesn't work if you are dynamically typing. If you just give it a value it works, but if you're feeding a value constantly dynamically the commas are added in the wrong place.

Comment: I have updated the demo below my answer. When entering a dynamic value in a textbox. you test try @EdgarQuintero

Comment: The currency formatting massively skews this: https://jsben.ch/u4gk0

Answer (score 48):

[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Native JS function. Supported by IE11, Edge, latest Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari on iOS and Chrome on Android.

```
var number = 3500;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number));
// → '3,500' if in US English locale
```

Comment: My answer was updated in response to your comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

I am quite impressed by the number of answers this question has got. I like the answer by *uKolka*:

```
n.toLocaleString()
```

But unfortunately, in some locales like Spanish, it does not work (IMHO) as expected for numbers below 10,000:

```
Number(1000).toLocaleString('ES-es')
```

Gives `1000` and not `1.000`.

See [toLocaleString not working on numbers less than 10000 in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628055/tolocalestring-not-working-on-numbers-less-than-10000-in-all-browsers) to know why.

So I had to use the answer by *Elias Zamaria* choosing the right thousands separator character:

```
n.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, Number(10000).toLocaleString().substring(2, 3))
```

This one works well as a one-liner for both locales that use `,` or `.` as the thousands separator and starts working from 1,000 in all cases.

```
Number(1000).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, Number(10000).toLocaleString().substring(2, 3))
```

Gives `1.000` with a Spanish locale context.

Should you want to have absolute control over the way a number is formatted, you may also try the following:

```
let number   = 1234.567
let decimals = 2
let decpoint = '.' // Or Number(0.1).toLocaleString().substring(1, 2)
let thousand = ',' // Or Number(10000).toLocaleString().substring(2, 3)

let n = Math.abs(number).toFixed(decimals).split('.')
n[0] = n[0].split('').reverse().map((c, i, a) =>
  i > 0 && i < a.length && i % 3 == 0 ? c + thousand : c
).reverse().join('')
let final = (Math.sign(number) < 0 ? '-' : '') + n.join(decpoint)

console.log(final)
```

Gives `1,234.57`.

This one does not need a regular expression. It works by adjusting the number to the desired amount of decimals with `toFixed` first, then dividing it around the decimal point `.` if there is one. The left side is then turned into an array of digits which is reversed. Then a thousands separator is added every three digits from the start and the result reversed again. The final result is the union of the two parts. The sign of the input number is removed with `Math.abs` first and then put back if necessary.

It is not a one-liner but not much longer and easily turned into a function. Variables have been added for clarity, but those may be substituted by their desired values if known in advance. You may use the expressions that use `toLocaleString` as a way to find out the right characters for the decimal point and the thousands separator for the current locale (bear in mind that those require a more modern Javascript.)

Answer (score 35):

Thanks to everyone for their replies. I have built off of some of the answers to make a more "one-size-fits-all" solution.

The first snippet adds a function that mimics [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)'s `number_format()` to the Number prototype. If I am formatting a number, I usually want decimal places so the function takes in the number of decimal places to show. Some countries use commas as the decimal and decimals as the thousands separator so the function allows these separators to be set.

```
Number.prototype.numberFormat = function(decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    dec_point = typeof dec_point !== 'undefined' ? dec_point : '.';
    thousands_sep = typeof thousands_sep !== 'undefined' ? thousands_sep : ',';

    var parts = this.toFixed(decimals).split('.');
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousands_sep);

    return parts.join(dec_point);
}
```

You would use this as follows:

```
var foo = 5000;
console.log(foo.numberFormat(2)); // us format: 5,000.00
console.log(foo.numberFormat(2, ',', '.')); // european format: 5.000,00
```

I found that I often needed to get the number back for math operations, but parseFloat converts 5,000 to 5, simply taking the first sequence of integer values. So I created my own float conversion function and added it to the String prototype.

```
String.prototype.getFloat = function(dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    dec_point = typeof dec_point !== 'undefined' ? dec_point : '.';
    thousands_sep = typeof thousands_sep !== 'undefined' ? thousands_sep : ',';

    var parts = this.split(dec_point);
    var re = new RegExp("[" + thousands_sep + "]");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(re, '');

    return parseFloat(parts.join(dec_point));
}
```

Now you can use both functions as follows:

```
var foo = 5000;
var fooString = foo.numberFormat(2); // The string 5,000.00
var fooFloat = fooString.getFloat(); // The number 5000;

console.log((fooString.getFloat() + 1).numberFormat(2)); // The string 5,001.00
```

Comment: Very nice, I borrowed the first method ;)
But it does not produce a correct result when you want to use a European format and the number is fractional. Line 5 should be:
`var parts = this.toFixed(decimals).toString().split('.');`

Comment: You are right! toFixed() changes the comma to a period and so the '.' should be used instead of `var dec_point`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: can    you make an  npm module for this?

Comment: @J.Money The .toString is unnecessary, toFixed already returns a string.

Comment: I don't know why you've mentioned PHP here at all, or given a prototipical function which already [exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Comment: @vsync The most important reason of all... browser compatibility.

Comment: @J.Money - first, it doesn't explain what PHP has to do with that, and second, you didn't mention that `numberFormat` is already in ES4, and what browsers does it supports: `chrome 24+, FF 29+, IE11+`. only then you should provide an optional polyfill, whom not everyone needs.

Answer (score 25):

I think this is the shortest regular expression that does it:

```
/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g

"123456".replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, ",")
```

I checked it on a few numbers and it worked.

Comment: works only well if you dont have float number with more than 3 numbers after the separator in this case a dot. Otherwise it adds a comma also.
"1234567890.1234567890".replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, ",") This would not work for example. Returns "1,234,567,890.1,234,567,890"

Comment: Works well for currency though! Just round your digits prior to adding commas.

Comment: It Adds , After Decimal point :
12.3456".replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, ",")   ==  12.3,456

Answer (score 22):

`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` would have been awesome if it was provided natively by all browsers *(Safari)*.

I checked all other answers but noone seemed to polyfill it. Here is a poc towards that, which is actually a combination of first two answers; if `toLocaleString` works it uses it, if it doesn't it uses a custom function.

```js
var putThousandsSeparators;

putThousandsSeparators = function(value, sep) {
  if (sep == null) {
    sep = ',';
  }
  // check if it needs formatting
  if (value.toString() === value.toLocaleString()) {
    // split decimals
    var parts = value.toString().split('.')
    // format whole numbers
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
    // put them back together
    value = parts[1] ? parts.join('.') : parts[0];
  } else {
    value = value.toLocaleString();
  }
  return value;
};

alert(putThousandsSeparators(1234567.890));
```

Comment: Be aware that the polyfill only works with numbers that have at most 3 decimals. For eg: `0.12345` will output `0.12,345`. A good implementation for this can be found in the [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/blob/master/numberFormat.js)

Comment: you're right, putting a `value > 1000` to the if condition fixes that case, however this was a poc and of course better tested versions can be found elsewhere, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: It's not sufficient to put `value > 1000`, because it would be the same for any number and more than 3 decimals. eg `1000.12345` returns `1,000.12,345`. Your answer is great and on the right path, but just not complete. I was only trying to point out for other people that may stumble on your answer and just copy/pasta it without testing with different input data.

Comment: alright, this needed another edit :) I agree, but now at least it should work for the most cases.

Answer (score 22):

You can either use this procedure to format your currency needing.

```
var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});
nf.format(123456.789); // ‘$123,456.79’
```

For more info you can access this link.

https://www.justinmccandless.com/post/formatting-currency-in-javascript/

Comment: This is the correct, portable, native answer. Wish I could upvote more than once.

Answer (score 21):

The thousands separator can be inserted in an international-friendly manner using the browser's `Intl` object:

```
Intl.NumberFormat().format(1234);
// returns "1,234" if the user's locale is en_US, for example
```

See [MDN's article on NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) for more, you can specify locale behavior or default to the user's. This is a little more foolproof because it respects local differences; many countries use periods to separate digits while a comma denotes the decimals.

Intl.NumberFormat isn't available in all browsers yet, but it works in latest Chrome, Opera, & IE. Firefox's next release should support it. Webkit doesn't seem to have a timeline for implementation.

Comment: While this would be awesome if we could use a simple built-in function, it has terrible browser implementation. For Example, IE 8-10 and all Safari doesnt support this

Comment: @BlaineKasten there's a fully compatible polyfill for older browsers available here: https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js it's huge, but it works.

Comment: Available via a pollyfill CDN (only returns what is needed based on useragent): https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl

Comment: Had issues formatting large numbers with toLocaleString, this worked great (with polyfill)

Answer (score 16):

if you are dealing with currency values and formatting a lot then it might be worth to add tiny [accounting.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/) which handles lot of edge cases and localization:

```
// Default usage:
accounting.formatMoney(12345678); // $12,345,678.00

// European formatting (custom symbol and separators), could also use options object as second param:
accounting.formatMoney(4999.99, "€", 2, ".", ","); // €4.999,99

// Negative values are formatted nicely, too:
accounting.formatMoney(-500000, "£ ", 0); // £ -500,000

// Simple `format` string allows control of symbol position [%v = value, %s = symbol]:
accounting.formatMoney(5318008, { symbol: "GBP",  format: "%v %s" }); // 5,318,008.00 GBP
```

Comment: Link does not work anymore. But looks similar to this one: http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

Answer (score 15):

Here's a simple function that inserts commas for thousand separators.  It uses array functions rather than a RegEx.

```
/**
 * Format a number as a string with commas separating the thousands.
 * @param num - The number to be formatted (e.g. 10000)
 * @return A string representing the formatted number (e.g. "10,000")
 */
var formatNumber = function(num) {
    var array = num.toString().split('');
    var index = -3;
    while (array.length + index > 0) {
        array.splice(index, 0, ',');
        // Decrement by 4 since we just added another unit to the array.
        index -= 4;
    }
    return array.join('');
};
```

CodeSandbox link with examples: https://codesandbox.io/s/p38k63w0vq

Comment: Hi.. This example is great. But it will put commas for the decimal part too. just an edit:

function formatNumber( num ) {
    var decimalPart = '';
    num = num.toString();
    if ( num.indexOf( '.' ) != -1 ) {
        decimalPart = '.'+ num.split( '.' )[1];
        num = parseInt(num.split( '.' )[0]);
    }
    var array = num.toString().split( '' );
    var index = -3;
    while ( array.length + index > 0 ) {
        array.splice( index, 0, ',' );
        // Decrement by 4 since we just added another unit to the array.
        index -= 4;
    }
    return array.join( '' ) + decimalPart;
};

Comment: Thank you, sir. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 15):

The following code uses char scan, so there's no regex.

```
function commafy( num){
  var parts = (''+(num<0?-num:num)).split("."), s=parts[0], L, i=L= s.length, o='';
  while(i--){ o = (i===0?'':((L-i)%3?'':',')) 
                  +s.charAt(i) +o }
  return (num<0?'-':'') + o + (parts[1] ? '.' + parts[1] : ''); 
}
```

It shows promising performance: http://jsperf.com/number-formatting-with-commas/5

2015.4.26: Minor fix to resolve issue when num<0. See https://jsfiddle.net/runsun/p5tqqvs3/

Comment: this doesn't work with `commafy(-123456)` it gives `-,123,456`

Comment: This is great! Thanks for putting together the jsperf

Comment: This snippet is an absolute monster, out performs everything.

Answer (score 14):

Use This code to handle currency format for india. Country code can be changed to handle other country currency.

```
let amount =350256.95
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});

// Use it.

formatter.format(amount);
```

output:

```
3,50,256.95
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde i will add additional context  to improve the answer sure

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) constructor. Here is how you can do it.

```
 resultNumber = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(yourNumber);
```

Comment: this not working node js. It is not giving response in Indian format

Answer (score 12):

#### Universal, fast, accurate, simple function

- Using RegEx (Fast & Accurate)
- Support Numbers(Float/Integer)/String/Multiple numbers in a string
- Smart well (Not grouping decimals - Compatible with different types of grouping)
- Support all browsers specially 'Safari' & 'IE' & many older browsers
- [Optional] Respecting non-English (**Persian**/**Arabic**) digits (+ Pre-fix)

###### TL;DR - Full version function (minified):

```js
// num: Number/s (String/Number),
// sep: Thousands separator (String) - Default: ','
// dec: Decimal separator (String) - Default: '.' (Just one char)
// u: Universal support for languages characters (String - RegEx character set / class) - Example: '[\\d\\u0660-\\u0669\\u06f0-\\u06f9]' (English/Persian/Arabic), Default: '\\d' (English)

function formatNums(num,sep,dec,u){sep=sep||',';u=u||'\\d';if(typeof num!='string'){num=String(num);if(dec&&dec!='.')num=num.replace('.',dec);}return num.replace(RegExp('\\'+(dec||'.')+u+'+|'+u+'(?=(?:'+u+'{3})+(?!'+u+'))','g'),function(a){return a.length==1?a+sep:a})}

text='100000000 English or Persian/Arabic ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹/٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩ this is 123123123.123123123 with this -123123 and these 10 100 1000 123123/123123 (2000000) .33333 100.00 or any like 500000Kg';

console.log(formatNums(10000000.0012));
console.log(formatNums(10000000.0012,'.',',')); // German
console.log(formatNums(text,',','.','[\\d\\u0660-\\u0669\\u06f0-\\u06f9]')); // Respect Persian/Arabic digits
```

```html
<input oninput="document.getElementById('result').textContent=formatNums(this.value)" placeholder="Type a number here">
<div id="result"></div>
```

##### Why NOT satisfied with other answers?

- [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) / [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)
  (Right answer)

  - If no well arguments, **we can't expect same result**. Also with arguments options we still can't be sure what can be the result because it will use local settings and possible client modifications effect on it or the browser/device not support it.
  - **>~2016 browsers support** and still in 2021 some reports that in some cases like `Safari` or `IE/Edge` do not return as expected.
  - `toLocaleString()` Work with numbers, `Intl.NumberFormat` Work with String/Numbers; Strings will be/have to be parsed and also rounded if necessary, so:

    - If we already have a localized string with `non-English digits` we have to replace numbers with the English one, then parse it, then use it again with the local options. (If it return what we expect)
    - Generally while parsing we cant expect not `missing decimal zeros` or details in `big numbers` or respecting `other languages numeral characters`
  - Decimal / Thousand separator characters can not be customized more than language options, except with post-fixings with replace() + RegEx again. *(For example in Persian usually we don't use the suggested Arabic comma and also sometime we use `∕` Fraction/Division slash as decimal separator)*
  - Slow performance in loops
- Not so good RegEx ways (Fastest & One-liner ways)

  - `/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/` it will group decimals too. `// 123,123.123,123 !!!`
  - `/(?<!\.\d+)\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/` used **look-behind** that not supported well yet. Please check:
    https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#browser_compatibility
    Note: Generally lookbehind can be against of original RegEx structure *(because of how the analyzer should work like do not buffer the raw behind as a parser)* and actually it can make the performance seriously low (In this case ~30%). *I think it pushed inside over the time by requests.*
  - `/\B(?=(?=\d*\.)(\d{3})+(?!\d))/` just work with float numbers and ignore integers.
  - `.replace(/(?:[^.\d]|^)\d+/g,function(a){return a.replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)/g,',');})` **(My old idea)** Using 2 RegEx. First one find the integer parts, second one put separator. Why 2 functions, when it can be mixed?
  - `/(\..*)$|(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g` (Good idea by [@djulien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4490816/) - i voted up) but when the RegEx is global, `(\..*)$` it can make a mistake even with a space in end.
    Also using capturing groups *(Example: `(\d)`)* will make the performance low so if it possible, use non-capturing groups *(Example: `(?:\d)`)* or if an statement already exist in our function let's mix it.
    In this case, not using capturing groups improve performance about ~20% and in case of `/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g` vs `/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)/g`, the second one is ~8% faster.
    About regex performances:
    [image: https://jsben.ch/HUmDA]
    *Note: Sure different methods, browsers, hardware, system status, cases and even changes on ECMAScript will effect on result of checking performance. But some changes logically should effect result and i used this one just as visual example.*
- Using library's like [Numeral.js](https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js) **so much not necessary functions** for a simple task.
- Heavy code / **Not accurate** functions that used `.split('.')` or `.toFixed()` or `Math.floor()` ...

---

#### Final result:

There is no best of all and it should be chosen based on the need. My priority of sorting;

1. Compatibility
2. Capability
3. Universality
4. Ease of use
5. Performance

##### `toLocaleString()` (Compatibility - Universality) [Native function]

- If you have to change digits and grouping from English to another language
- If you are not sure about your client language
- If you don't need to have exact expected result
- If you don't care about older version of Safari

```
// 1000000.2301
parseFloat(num) // (Pre-fix) If the input is string
    .toLocaleString('en-US', {
        useGrouping: true // (Default is true, here is just for show)
    });
// 1,000,000.23
```

Read more: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring_number.asp

##### `Intl.NumberFormat()` (Capability - Universality - Compatibility) [Native function]

Almost same as `toLocaleString()` +

- Great capability of supporting currency, units, etc... any language **(Modern browsers)**

```
// 1000000.2301
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { // It can be 'fa-IR' : Farsi - Iran
    numberingSystem: 'arab'
}).format(num)
// ١٬٠٠٠٬٠٠٠٫٢٣
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat

With these much options of the native functions, we still can not expect:

- Exact result (+ Not parsing the input / Not rounding / Not converting big numbers)
- Accepting other languages digits as input
- Customizing separators
- Trusting browsers support
- Performance

So you maybe need a function like any of these:

##### `formatNums()` (Compatibility - Ease of use)

**Full version (Capability)** *(Not faster than toLocaleString)* - Explain:

```
function formatNums(num, sep, dec, u) {
    // Setting defaults
    sep = sep || ','; // Seperator
    u = u || '\\d'; // Universal character set \d: 0-9 (English)
    // Mixing of Handeling numbers when the decimal character should be changed + Being sure the input is string
    if (typeof num != 'string') {
        num = String(num);
        if (dec && dec != '.') num = num.replace('.', dec); // Replacing sure decimal character with the custom
    }
    //
    return num.replace(RegExp('\\' + (dec || '.') + u + '+|' + u + '(?=(?:' + u + '{3})+(?!' + u + '))', 'g'),
        // The RegEx will be like /\.\d+|\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g if not be customized 
        // RegEx explain:
        // 1) \.\d+  :  First try to get any part that started with a dot and followed by any much of English digits, one or more (For ignoring it later)
        // 2) |  :  Or
        // 3) \d  :  Get any 1 char digit
        // 3.1) (?=...)  :  That the next of that should be
        // 3.2) (?:\d{3})  :  3 length digits
        // 3.2.1) +  :  One or more of the group
        // 3.3) (?!\d)  :  ...till any place that there is no digits
        function(a) { // Any match can be the decimal part or the integer part so lets check it
            return a.length == 1 ? a + sep : a // If the match is one character, it is from the grouping part as item (3) in Regex explain so add the seperator next of it, if not, ignore it and return it back.
        })
}
```

```js
function formatNums(num,sep,dec,u) {
    sep=sep||',';
    u=u||'\\d';
    if(typeof num!='string') {
        num=String(num);
        if( dec && dec!='.') num=num.replace('.',dec);
    }
    return num.replace(RegExp('\\'+(dec||'.')+u+'+|'+u+'(?=(?:'+u+'{3})+(?!'+u+'))','g'),function(a) {return a.length==1 ? a+sep : a})
}
console.log(formatNums(1000000.2301));
console.log(formatNums(100.2301));
console.log(formatNums(-2000.2301));
console.log(formatNums(123123123,' , '));
console.log(formatNums('0000.0000'));
console.log(formatNums('5000000.00'));
console.log(formatNums('5000000,00',' ',','));
console.log(formatNums(5000000.1234,' ',','));
console.log(formatNums('۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹/۹۰۰۰',',','/','[\\d\\u0660-\\u0669\\u06f0-\\u06f9]'));
```

Play with the examples here:
https://jsfiddle.net/PAPIONbit/198xL3te/

**Light version (Performance)** *(~30% faster than toLocaleString)*

```js
function formatNums(num,sep) {
    sep=sep||',';
    return String(num).replace(/\.\d+|\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,
        function(a) {
            return a.length==1?a+sep:a
        }
    );
}
console.log(formatNums(1000000.2301));
console.log(formatNums(100.2301));
console.log(formatNums(-2000.2301));
console.log(formatNums(123123123,' '));
```

Check the RegEx (Without the necessary function) : https://regexr.com/66ott

##### `(num+'').replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)/g,',');` (Performance - Compatibility)

Best choose if The input is Specified / Predefined. (Like usual prices that sure will not have more than 3 decimals)
*(~65% faster than toLocaleString)*

```js
num=1000000;
str='123123.100';
console.log((num+'').replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)/g,','));
console.log(str.replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)/g,','));
```

**+**

###### For Persian/Arabic local clients:

If your client going to use Persian/Arabic numbers for input as what is usual in Iran, I think the best way is instead of keeping the original characters, convert them to English before you deal with, to you can calculate it.

```
// ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰
function toEnNum(n) { // Replacing Persian/Arabic numbers character with English
    n.replace(/[\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9]/g, // RegEx unicode range Persian/Arabic numbers char
        function(c) {
            return c.charCodeAt(0) & 0xf; // Replace the char with real number by getting the binary index and breaking to lowest using 15
        }
    );
}
// 1234567890
```

And for still showing them as original looking there is 2 ways:

- **CSS** Using Persian/Arabic fonts with local digits (My choose)
- Convert the result back with `Intl.NumberFormat` or a function like:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13787021/7514010

---

**My Old-school function** on this post: *(~15% Faster than toLocalString)*

```
// 10000000.0012
function formatNums(n, s) {
    return s = s || ",", String(n).
    replace(/(?:^|[^.\d])\d+/g, // First this RegEx take just integer parts
        function(n) {
            return n.replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)/g, s);
        })
}
// 10,000,000.0012
```

Comment: This is not code golf. I think it is OK to use some spaces and newlines to make your code more readable, even if they are not strictly required.

Comment: @elias-zamaria check it out now by the new function, i removed negative behind look because not support in all browsers

Answer (score 11):

```
var formatNumber = function (number) {
  var splitNum;
  number = Math.abs(number);
  number = number.toFixed(2);
  splitNum = number.split('.');
  splitNum[0] = splitNum[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  return splitNum.join(".");
}
```

EDIT:
The function only work with positive number. for exmaple:

```
var number = -123123231232;
formatNumber(number)
```

Output: "123,123,231,232"

But to answer the question above `toLocaleString()` method just solves the problem.

```
var number = 123123231232;
    number.toLocaleString()
```

Output: "123,123,231,232"

Cheer!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Nice script, but it does not work with negative numbers.

Answer (score 9):

My answer is the only answer that completely replaces jQuery with a much more sensible alternative:

```
function $(dollarAmount)
{
    const locale = 'en-US';
    const options = { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' };
    return Intl.NumberFormat(locale, options).format(dollarAmount);
}
```

This solution not only adds commas, but it also rounds to the nearest penny in the event that you input an amount like `$(1000.9999)` you'll get $1,001.00. Additionally, the value you input can safely be a number or a string; it doesn't matter.

If you're dealing with money, but don't want a leading dollar sign shown on the amount, you can also add this function, which uses the previous function but removes the `$`:

```
function no$(dollarAmount)
{
    return $(dollarAmount).replace('$','');
}
```

If you're **not** dealing with money, and have varying decimal formatting requirements, here's a more versatile function:

```
function addCommas(number, minDecimalPlaces = 0, maxDecimalPlaces = Math.max(3,minDecimalPlaces))
{
    const options = {};
    options.maximumFractionDigits = maxDecimalPlaces;
    options.minimumFractionDigits = minDecimalPlaces;
    return Intl.NumberFormat('en-US',options).format(number);
}
```

Oh, and by the way, the fact that this code does not work in some old version of Internet Explorer is completely intentional. I try to break IE anytime that I can catch it not supporting modern standards.

Please remember that excessive praise, in the comment section, is considered off-topic. Instead, just shower me with up-votes.

Comment: The Number(n).toLocaleString() seems the best answer but you'd probably want to use something like new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(n) rather than stripping off dollar signs and decimals if all the user wants is commas in their number.

Comment: @bmacnaughton : That's a good point when you're not dealing with money. However, if you're dealing with money, and just "don't want the leading dollar sign", Number(1000.50).toLocaleString() produces '1,000.5', which removes the insignificant zero that's typically kept when displaying money values. Good comment though: everyone should know what you've said.

Answer (score 8):

I Wrote this one before stumbling on this post. No regex and you can actually understand the code.

```js
$(function(){
  
  function insertCommas(s) {

    // get stuff before the dot
    var d = s.indexOf('.');
    var s2 = d === -1 ? s : s.slice(0, d);

    // insert commas every 3 digits from the right
    for (var i = s2.length - 3; i > 0; i -= 3)
      s2 = s2.slice(0, i) + ',' + s2.slice(i);

    // append fractional part
    if (d !== -1)
      s2 += s.slice(d);

    return s2;

  }
  
  
  $('#theDudeAbides').text( insertCommas('1234567.89012' ) );
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="theDudeAbides"></div>
```

Comment: I added s.toString() at beginning of function so it can accept numbers too, not just strings.  This is my preferred answer because it is readable, concise, and has none of the bugs the regex answers seem to have.

Comment: only works if you pass it a string.. an easy fix but just wanted to note it

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple reusable function that returns a string with the specified number of decimal places and lets you toggle the inclusion of a comma.

```
function format_number(number, num_decimals, include_comma)
{
    return number.toLocaleString('en-US', {useGrouping: include_comma, minimumFractionDigits: num_decimals, maximumFractionDigits: num_decimals});
}
```

Usage examples:

```
format_number(1234.56789, 2, true); // Returns '1,234.57'
format_number(9001.42, 0, false); // Returns '9001'
```

If you need to customize the string further, you can find the list of formatting options [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat).

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who likes 1-liners and a single regex, but *doesn't* want to use split(), here is an enhanced version of the regex from other answers that handles (ignores) decimal places:

```
    var formatted = (x+'').replace(/(\..*)$|(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, (digit, fract) => fract || digit + ',');
```

The regex *first* matches a substring starting with a literal "." and replaces it with itself ("fract"), and *then* matches any digit followed by multiples of 3 digits and puts "," after it.

For example, *x* = 12345678.12345678 will give *formatted* = '12,345,678.12345678'.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative way, supporting decimals, different separators and negatives.

```
var number_format = function(number, decimal_pos, decimal_sep, thousand_sep) {
    var ts      = ( thousand_sep == null ? ',' : thousand_sep )
        , ds    = ( decimal_sep  == null ? '.' : decimal_sep )
        , dp    = ( decimal_pos  == null ? 2   : decimal_pos )

        , n     = Math.floor(Math.abs(number)).toString()

        , i     = n.length % 3 
        , f     = ((number < 0) ? '-' : '') + n.substr(0, i)
    ;

    for(;i<n.length;i+=3) {
        if(i!=0) f+=ts;
        f+=n.substr(i,3);
    }

    if(dp > 0) 
        f += ds + parseFloat(number).toFixed(dp).split('.')[1]

    return f;
}
```

Some corrections by @Jignesh Sanghani, don't forget to upvote his comment.

Comment: Perfect for me, just added a new line to remove formatting before processing.

Comment: `fn.substr(0, i)` replace with `n.substr(0, i)` and also `number.toFixed(dp).split('.')[1]` replace with `parseFloat(number).toFixed(dp).split('.')[1]`. because when i use directly it's give me en error. please update your code

Comment: flawed. number grows. an exampel call would have been great!

Comment: switching ceil to floor fixed that but unsure what other issues will arise.

Comment: i just saw your comment, however, i remember the issue was not that simple. ceil was also flawed in some cases. just checked. if the number is negative. therefore abs should come before floor.

Comment: Try Math.floor(-75.1) ;)

Answer (score 6):

Let me try to improve [uKolka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286601/ukolka)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript/17663871#17663871) and maybe help others save some time.

Use [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/).

```js
document.body.textContent = numeral(1234567).format('0,0');
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

You should go with [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) only if its [browser compatibilty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#AutoCompatibilityTable) is not an issue.

Comment: this inspired me to npm install numeral

Answer (score 6):

Just for future Googlers (or not necessarily 'Googlers'):

All of solutions mentioned above are wonderful, however, RegExp might be awfully bad thing to use in a situation like that.

So, yes, you might use some of the options proposed or even write something primitive yet useful like:

```
const strToNum = str => {

   //Find 1-3 digits followed by exactly 3 digits & a comma or end of string
   let regx = /(\d{1,3})(\d{3}(?:,|$))/;
   let currStr;

   do {
       currStr = (currStr || str.split(`.`)[0])
           .replace( regx, `$1,$2`)
   } while (currStr.match(regx)) //Stop when there's no match & null's returned

   return ( str.split(`.`)[1] ) ?
           currStr.concat(`.`, str.split(`.`)[1]) :
           currStr;

};

strToNum(`123`) // => 123
strToNum(`123456`) // => 123,456
strToNum(`-1234567.0987`) // => -1,234,567.0987
```

The regexp that's used here is fairly simple and the loop will go precisely the number of times it takes to get the job done.

And you might optimize it far better, "DRYify" code & so on.

Yet,

```
(-1234567.0987).toLocaleString();
```

(in most situations) would be a far better choice.

The point is not in the speed of execution or in cross-browser compatibility.

In situations when you'd like to show the resulting number to user, .toLocaleString() method gives you superpower to speak the same language with the user of your website or app (whatever her/his language is).

This method according to ECMAScript documentation was introduced in 1999, and I believe that the reason for that was the hope that the Internet at some point will connect people all around the world, so, some "internalization" tools were needed.

Today the Internet does connect all of us, so, it is important to remember that the world is a way more complex that we might imagine & that (/almost) **all of us are here**, in the Internet.

Obviously, considering the diversity of people, it is impossible to guarantee perfect UX for everybody because we speak different languages, value different things, etc. And exactly because of this, it is even more important to try to localize things as much as it's possible.

So, considering that there're some particular standards for representation of date, time, numbers, etc. & that we have a tool to display those things in the format preferred by the final user, isn't that rare and almost irresponsible not to use that tool (especially in situations when we want to display this data to the user)?

For me, using RegExp instead of .toLocaleString() in situation like that sounds a little bit like creating a clock app with JavaScript & hard-coding it in such a way so it'll display Prague time only (which would be quite useless for people who don't live in Prague) even though the default behaviour of

```
new Date();
```

is to return the data according to final user's clock.

Comment: why did you write the function with const  and => ?

Comment: @OGSean I always do since it's the most convenient way of declaring variables & functions. Also, I think it helps to keep the code cleaner & shorter.

Comment: This is the right answer, people are wildly overcomplicating this. `toLocaleString()` is built for this exact use case.

Answer (score 5):

I think your solution is one of the shorter ones I've seen for this. I don't think there are any standard JavaScript functions to do this sort of thing, so you're probably on your own.

I checked the CSS 3 specifications to see whether it's possible to do this in CSS, but unless you want every digit in its own `<span>`, I don't think that's possible.

I did find one project on [Google Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code) that looked promising: [flexible-js-formatting](http://code.google.com/p/flexible-js-formatting/). I haven't used it, but it looks pretty flexible and has unit tests using [JsUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit). The developer also has a lot of posts (though old) about this topic.

Be sure to consider international users: lots of nations use a space as the separator and use the comma for separating the decimal from the integral part of the number.

Comment: Could you post the solution using CSS only & spans?

Answer (score 5):

I think this function will take care of all the issues related to this problem.

```
function commaFormat(inputString) {
    inputString = inputString.toString();
    var decimalPart = "";
    if (inputString.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        //alert("decimal number");
        inputString = inputString.split(".");
        decimalPart = "." + inputString[1];
        inputString = inputString[0];
        //alert(inputString);
        //alert(decimalPart);

    }
    var outputString = "";
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = inputString.length - 1; i >= 0 && inputString.charAt(i) != '-'; i--) {
        //alert("inside for" + inputString.charAt(i) + "and count=" + count + " and outputString=" + outputString);
        if (count == 3) {
            outputString += ",";
            count = 0;
        }
        outputString += inputString.charAt(i);
        count++;
    }
    if (inputString.charAt(0) == '-') {
        outputString += "-";
    }
    //alert(outputString);
    //alert(outputString.split("").reverse().join(""));
    return outputString.split("").reverse().join("") + decimalPart;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Lots of good answers already. Here's another, just for fun:

```
function format(num, fix) {
    var p = num.toFixed(fix).split(".");
    return p[0].split("").reduceRight(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
        if ("-" === num && 0 === i) {
            return num + acc;
        }
        var pos = orig.length - i - 1
        return  num + (pos && !(pos % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
    }, "") + (p[1] ? "." + p[1] : "");
}
```

Some examples:

```
format(77.03453, 2); // "77.03"
format(78436589374); // "78,436,589,374"
format(784, 4);      // "784.0000"
format(-123456);     // "-123,456"
```

Comment: this doesn't work with `format(-123456)` it gives `-,123,456`

Comment: Fixed (although there is probably a more elegant way to do it without checking for the sign every time). In any event, the update makes this work with negative numbers.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a short and sweet solution:

```js
const number = 12345678.99;

const numberString = String(number).replace(
    /^\d+/,
    number => [...number].map(
        (digit, index, digits) => (
            !index || (digits.length - index) % 3 ? '' : ','
        ) + digit
    ).join('')
);

// numberString: 12,345,678.99
```

Comment: That is telling me "Uncaught TypeError: number is not iterable". Maybe you need to call `toString` on the number.

Comment: @EliasZamaria sorry, I used a string in my case. Updated my answer to convert to string.

Comment: I tried 12.34 as the number and it returned `12,.34`.

Comment: I thought it was only meant to work with decimals. Updated for you.

Answer (score 4):

## My **“*true*”** regular-expressions-only solution <sub>for those love one-liners</sub>

You see those enthusiastic players above? Maybe you can golf out of it. Here’s my stroke.

```
n => `${n}`.replace(/(?<!\.\d+)\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, " ").replace(/(?<=\.(\d{3})+)\B/g, " ")
```

<sub>Uses a  <sub>THIN SPACE</sub> (U+2009) for a thousands separator, as the *International System of Units* said to do in [the eighth edition<sub>(2006)</sub> of their publication “*SI Brochure: The International System of Units (SI)*”](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8.pdf) (See §5.3.4.). [The ninth edition<sub>(2019)</sub>](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9.pdf) suggests to use a *space* for it (See §5.4.4.). You can use whatever you want, including a comma.</sub>

---

### See.

```js
const integer_part_only = n => `${n}`.replace(/(?<!\.\d+)\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, " I ");
const fractional_part_only = n => `${n}`.replace(/(?<=\.(\d{3})+)\B/g, " F ");
const both = n => fractional_part_only(integer_part_only(n));

function demo(number) { // I’m using Chrome 74.
 console.log(`${number}
  → "${integer_part_only(number)}" (integer part only)
  → "${fractional_part_only(number)}" (fractional part only)
  → "${both(number)}" (both)
 `);
}
demo(Math.random() * 10e5);
demo(123456789.01234567);
demo(123456789);
demo(0.0123456789);
```

---

### How does it work?

#### For an integer part

```
.replace(/(?<!\.\d+)\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, " I ")
```

- `.replace(……, " I ")` Put “ I ”

  - `/……/g` at each of

    - `\B` the in-between of two adjacent digits

      - `(?=……)`<sub>POSITIVE LOOKAHEAD</sub> whose right part is

        - `(\d{3})+` one or more three-digit chunks
        - `\b` followed by a non-digit, such as, a period, the ending of the string, et cetera,
      - `(?<!……)`<sub>NEGATIVE LOOKBEHIND</sub> excluding ones whose left part

        - `\.\d+` is a dot followed by digits (“has a decimal separator”).

#### For a decimal part

```
.replace(/(?<=\.(\d{3})+)\B/g, " F ")
```

- `.replace(……, " F ")` Put “ F ”

  - `/……/g` at each of

    - `\B` the in-between of two adjacent digits

      - `(?<=……)`<sub>POSITIVE LOOKBEHIND</sub> whose left part is

        - `\.` a decimal separator
        - `(\d{3})+` followed by one or more three-digit chunks.

---

### [Character classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes) and [boundaries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Boundaries)

> #### `\d`
>
> Matches any digit (Arabic numeral). Equivalent to `[0-9]`.
>
> For example,
>
> - `/\d/` or `/[0-9]/` matches `2` in `B2 is the suite number`.
>
> #### `\b`
>
> Matches a **word boundary**. This is the position where a word character is not followed or preceded by another word-character, such as between a letter and a space. Note that a matched word boundary is not included in the match. In other words, the length of a matched word boundary is zero.
>
> Examples:
>
> - `/\bm/` matches the `m` in `moon` ;
> - `/oo\b/` does not match the `oo` in `moon`, because `oo` is followed by `n` which is a word character;
> - `/oon\b/` matches the `oon` in `moon`, because `oon` is the end of the string, thus not followed by a word character;
> - `/\w\b\w/` will never match anything, because a word character can never be followed by both a non-word and a word character.
>
> #### `\B`
>
> Matches a **non-word boundary**. This is a position where the previous and next character are of the same type: either both must be words, or both must be non-words. Such as between two letters or between two spaces. The beginning and end of a string are considered non-words. Same as the matched word boundary, the matched non-word boundary is also not included in the match.
>
> For example,
>
> - `/\Bon/` matches `on` in `at noon`;
> - `/ye\B/` matches `ye` in `possibly yesterday`.

---

### Browser compatibility

- https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind

Answer (score 4):

```js
var floatingNumber = 1000000.06665656676709;
var doubleNumber = floatingNumber.toFixed(2);
var athousand = parseFloat(doubleNumber).toLocaleString();
document.write(athousand);
```

Answer (score 3):

I added tofixed to **Aki143S**'s solution.
This solution uses dots for thousands separators and comma for the precision.

```
function formatNumber( num, fixed ) { 
    var decimalPart;

    var array = Math.floor(num).toString().split('');
    var index = -3; 
    while ( array.length + index > 0 ) { 
        array.splice( index, 0, '.' );              
        index -= 4;
    }

    if(fixed > 0){
        decimalPart = num.toFixed(fixed).split(".")[1];
        return array.join('') + "," + decimalPart; 
    }
    return array.join(''); 
};
```

Examples;

```
formatNumber(17347, 0)  = 17.347
formatNumber(17347, 3)  = 17.347,000
formatNumber(1234563.4545, 3)  = 1.234.563,454
```

Answer (score 3):

Related to @[elias-zamaria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28324/elias-zamaria) and @[t.j.crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)

A negative lookbehind for Safari browser is can't use `<`. So, it would be `(?!\.\d*)`

```
function numberWithCommas(n) {
  return n.toString().replace(/\B(?!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

It works for Safari and Firefox

Answer (score 2):

The solution from @user1437663 is great.

Who really understands the solution is being prepared to understand complex regular expressions.

A small improvement to make it more readable:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?=$))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
}
```

The pattern starts with **\B** to avoid use comma at the beginning of a word. Interestingly, the pattern is returned empty because **\B** does not advance the "cursor" (the same applies to **$**).

O **\B** is followed by a less known resources but is a powerful feature from Perl's regular expressions.

```
            Pattern1 (? = (Pattern2) ).
```

The magic is that what is in parentheses (*Pattern2*) is a pattern that follows the previous pattern (*Pattern1*) but without advancing the cursor and also is not part of the pattern returned. It is a kind of future pattern. This is similar when someone looks forward but really doesn't walk!

In this case *pattern2* is

```
\d{3})+(?=$)
```

It means 3 digits (one or more times) followed by the end of the string ($)

Finally, **Replace** method changes all occurrences of the pattern found (empty string) for comma. This only happens in cases where the remaining piece is a multiple of 3 digits 
(such cases where future cursor reach the end of the origin).

Answer (score 2):

After not finding a modern and comprehensive solution here, I have written an arrow function (without regex) to solve the formatting problem and it allows the caller to provide number of **fraction digits** as well as the **period and thousand separator** for Europe and rest of the world.

> Examples:
>
> ```
> numberFormatter(1234567890.123456) => 1,234,567,890
> numberFormatter(1234567890.123456, 4) => 1,234,567,890.1235
> numberFormatter(1234567890.123456, 4, '.', ',') => 1.234.567.890,1235 Europe
> ```

Here is the function written in **ES6** (modern syntax):

```
const numberFormatter = (number, fractionDigits = 0, thousandSeperator = ',', fractionSeperator = '.') => {
    if (number!==0 && !number || !Number.isFinite(number)) return number
    const frDigits = Number.isFinite(fractionDigits)? Math.min(Math.max(fractionDigits, 0), 7) : 0
    const num = number.toFixed(frDigits).toString()

    const parts = num.split('.')
    let digits = parts[0].split('').reverse()
    let sign = ''
    if (num < 0) {sign = digits.pop()}
    let final = []
    let pos = 0

    while (digits.length > 1) {
        final.push(digits.shift())
        pos++
        if (pos % 3 === 0) {final.push(thousandSeperator)}
    }
    final.push(digits.shift())
    return `${sign}${final.reverse().join('')}${frDigits > 0 ? fractionSeperator : ''}${frDigits > 0 && parts[1] ? parts[1] : ''}`
}
```

It has been **tested for negative, bad input and NaN cases**. If the input is **NaN** then it simply returns it.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var number = 1234567;
var formattedNumber = number.toLocaleString();

console.log(formattedNumber); // Output: 1,234,567
```

If you want to force a specific locale or customize the formatting options, you can pass them as arguments to the toLocaleString method.

```js
var number = 1234567;
var formattedNumber = number.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'decimal' });

console.log(formattedNumber); // Output: 1,234,567
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is good solution with less coding...

```
var y = "";
var arr = x.toString().split("");
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    y += arr[i];
    if((arr.length-i-1)%3==0 && i<arr.length-1) y += ",";
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for `-123456` it gives `-1,234,56`

Comment: that still doesn't work when the input is `-123456`. it gives `-,123,456` http://jsfiddle.net/wrossmck/2R8mD/1/

Comment: this is just crazy :)

Comment: Haha I agree with petr its fun to look at though.

Comment: this allows characters like abcdef and so on.. which should be restricted

Comment: You could also loop through  ```x.toString().length``` and use  ```x[i]```

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted your code to work in TextBox (Input type="text") so we can enter and delete digits in real time without losing cursor. It's works also if you select range when you delete. And you can use arrows and home/end buttons freely.
Thanks for saving my time!

```
//function controls number format as "1,532,162.3264321"
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode >= '35' && e.keyCode <= '40') return; //skip arrow-keys
    var selStart = x.selectionStart, selEnd = x.selectionEnd; //save cursor positions
    var parts = x.value.toString().split(".");
    var part0len = parts[0].length; //old length to check if new ',' would be added. Need for correcting new cursor position (+1 to right).

    //if user deleted ',' - remove previous number instead (without selection)
    if (x.selectionLength == 0 && (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46)) {//if pressed 8-backspace or 46-delete button
        var delPos = parts[0].search(/\d{4}/);
        if (delPos != -1) {//if found 4 digits in a row (',' is deleted)
            if (e.keyCode == 8) {//if backspace flag
                parts[0] = parts[0].slice(0, selStart - 1) + parts[0].slice(selEnd, parts[0].length);
                selEnd--;
                if (selStart > selEnd) selStart = selEnd;
            } else {
                parts[0] = parts[0].slice(0, selStart) + parts[0].slice(selEnd + 1, parts[0].length);
                selStart++;
                if (selEnd < selStart) selEnd = selStart;
            }
        }
    }

   var hasMinus = parts[0][0] == '-';
   parts[0] = (hasMinus ? '-' : '') + parts[0].replace(/[^\d]*/g, ""); //I'd like to clear old ',' to avoid things like 1,2,3,5,634.443216
   parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); //sets ',' between each 3 digits
   if (part0len < parts[0].length) { //move cursor to right if added new ','
       selStart++;
       selEnd++;
   } else if (part0len > parts[0].length) { //..or if removed last one ','
       selStart--;
       selEnd--;
   }
   x.value = parts.join(".");
   x.setSelectionRange(selStart, selEnd); //restoring cursor position
}
function saveSelectionLength(x) {
    x.selectionLength = x.selectionEnd - x.selectionStart;
}
```

To use this just added two events - onKeyUp and onKeyDown

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="val" Width="180px" onKeyUp="numberWithCommas(this);" onKeyDown="saveSelectionLength(this);"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found an approach that works in every situation. [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zmvxjpj6x)

```
function commas(n) {
  if (n < 1000) {
    return n + ''
  } else {
    // Convert to string.
    n += ''

    // Skip scientific notation.
    if (n.indexOf('e') !== -1) {
      return n
    }

    // Support fractions.
    let i = n.indexOf('.')
    let f = i == -1 ? '' : n.slice(i)
    if (f) n = n.slice(0, i)

    // Add commas.
    i = n.length
    n = n.split('')
    while (i > 3) n.splice((i -= 3), 0, ',')
    return n.join('') + f
  }
}
```

This is like [Noah Freitas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418247/2228559), but with support for **fractions** and **scientific notation**.

I think `toLocaleString` is the best choice, if performance is not a concern.

**edit:** Here's a CodeSandbox with some examples: https://codesandbox.io/s/zmvxjpj6x

Comment: I tried `commas(12345.67)` and got "12,345.6700000000000728".

Comment: @EliasZamaria whoops! forgot about imprecise arithmetic. fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let formatNumber = (number) => {
    let str = String(number)

    return str.split('').reduce(
        (a, b, i) => a + (i && !((str.length - i) % 3) ? ',' : '') + b,
        ''
    )
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution without regexp I ever saw.

Comment: @doctorgu it is very concise but not perf optimal.
thank you for bringing that up for me i took more time to play with it and found even performance differences between node, deno and bun.
here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73861853/3949619

Answer (score 0):

Yet another..(for int's as the question asks)

```
function insertCommas(str)
{
    var a = str.split("");
    a.reverse();

    var t, i = 0, arr = Array();

    while (t = a.shift())
    {
       if (((i++ % 3) == 0) && arr.length > 0)
           arr.unshift(",");
       arr.unshift(t);
    }

    return arr.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd share a little trick which I'm using for large number formatting.
Instead of inserting commas or spaces, I insert an empty but visible span in between the "thousands". This makes thousands easily visible, but it allows to copy/paste the input in the original format, without commas/spaces.

```
// This function accepts an integer, and produces a piece of HTML that shows it nicely with 
// some empty space at "thousand" markers. 
// Note, these space are not spaces, if you copy paste, they will not be visible.
function valPrettyPrint(orgVal) {
  // Save after-comma text, if present
  var period = orgVal.indexOf(".");
  var frac = period >= 0 ? orgVal.substr(period) : "";
  // Work on input as an integer
  var val = "" + Math.trunc(orgVal);
  var res = "";
  while (val.length > 0) {
    res = val.substr(Math.max(0, val.length - 3), 3) + res;
    val = val.substr(0, val.length - 3);
    if (val.length > 0) {
        res = "<span class='thousandsSeparator'></span>" + res;
    }
  }
  // Add the saved after-period information
  res += frac;
  return res;
}
```

With this CSS:

```
.thousandsSeparator {
  display : inline;
  padding-left : 4px;
}
```

See an example [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/marcinzukowski/ovfd83py/)

Comment: You could still show commas while allowing copy/paste the input in the original format by using css: 

`.thousandsSeparator:before{ content: ','; }`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Dandalf/ze6agw7v/

Comment: Oh wait. It just adds a comma before. Your still render using the Javascript from my example. So I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I have taken this a step further by displaying un-selectable commas: https://jsfiddle.net/ovfd83py/13/

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using AngularJS, there's this currency filter that may definitely help: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_currency.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try:

EDIT: Added in decimals

```js
function splitMille(n, separator = ',') {
  // Cast to string
  let num = (n + '')

  // Test for and get any decimals (the later operations won't support them)
  let decimals = ''
  if (/\./.test(num)) {
    // This regex grabs the decimal point as well as the decimal numbers
    decimals = num.replace(/^.*(\..*)$/, '$1')
  }
  
  // Remove decimals from the number string
  num = num.replace(decimals, '')
    // Reverse the number string through Array functions
    .split('').reverse().join('')
    // Split into groups of 1-3 characters (with optional supported character "-" for negative numbers)
    .match(/[0-9]{1,3}-?/g)
    // Add in the mille separator character and reverse back
    .join(separator).split('').reverse().join('')

  // Put the decimals back and output the formatted number
  return `${num}${decimals}`
}

let testA = splitMille(1234)
let testB = splitMille(-1234)
let testC = splitMille(123456.789)
let testD = splitMille(9007199254740991)
let testE = splitMille(1000.0001)

console.log('Results!\n\tA: %s\n\tB: %s\n\tC: %s\n\tD: %s\n\tE: %s', testA, testB, testC, testD, testE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line function with int & decimal support. I left some code in to convert the number to a string as well.

```
    function numberWithCommas(x) {
        return (x=x+'').replace(new RegExp('\\B(?=(\\d{3})+'+(~x.indexOf('.')?'\\.':'$')+')','g'),',');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function on the Number prototype

```js
Number.prototype.format = function (s, d) {
  return (
    this.toString()
      .split(".")
      .map((n, i) =>
        i
          ? n
          : n
              .split("")
              .map((n, i) => (i % 3 || !i ? n : s + n))
              .join("")
      )
      .join(d)
  );
};

console.log((8800.00).format(',', '.'))
// 8,880.00

// French notation
console.log((8800.00).format(' ', ','))
// 8 880,00
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with complexity of `n(Math.floor(str.length / 3))` instead of `n(str.length)`

```
function formatNumber(num) {
  let str = String(num)
  
  if (num < 1000) return str

  let result = ''

  for (let i = Math.floor(str.length / 3); i >= 0; i--) {
    let start = str.length - 3 * (i + 1)
    let end = start + 3

    result +=
      (end ? str.slice(Math.max(0, start), end) : '') + (end && i ? ',' : '')
  }

  return result
}
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what advantage this has over the other answers. Also, I ran `formatNumber(6543.21)` and got `6,543,.21`, which looks kind of strange with that extra comma.

Comment: @EliasZamaria i did not cover the decimal part. Instead of going char by char, you lower the number of iterations to / 3

Comment: Less loop is effective but this version is using `for` less effective than `reduce`, and using `slice` and `max` function for each loop. I did not compare this version and old version but I think your old version is more effective in real world because most numbers we are using is less than million.

Comment: I added another solution that increases 3 in each step based on your idea. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73883985/2958717

Answer (score 0):

I challenge with another solution.

First code was this.

```js
function formatNumber(number) {
  if (number < 1000) {
    return String(number);
  }
  if (number < 1000000) {
    let numbers = String(number).split('');
    numbers.splice(-3, 0, ',');
    return numbers.join('');
  }
  if (number < 1000000000) {
    let numbers = String(number).split('');
    numbers.splice(-3, 0, ',');
    numbers.splice(-7, 0, ',');
    return numbers.join('');
  }
  if (number < 1000000000000) {
    let numbers = String(number).split('');
    numbers.splice(-3, 0, ',');
    numbers.splice(-7, 0, ',');
    numbers.splice(-11, 0, ',');
    return numbers.join('');
  }

  throw new Error(`number: ${number} is too big`);
}
```

This code is lengthy and not scalable, but it is effective because it checks number itself not length of string that was converted from number.

So I converted to neat code based on this idea.
(You can make `12` more bigger to prevent error.)

```js
function formatNumber(number) {
  let commas = -1;
  for (let n3 = 3; n3 <= 12; n3 += 3) {
    commas++;
    const max = Math.pow(10, n3);
    if (number < max) {
      let numbers = String(number).split('');
      for (let i = 0; i < commas; i++) {
        numbers.splice(-(3 * (i + 1) + i), 0, ',');
      }
      return numbers.join('');
    }
  }

  throw new Error(`number: ${number} is too big`);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found this answer somewhere earlier , and I updated it to allow negative numbers.

You can use it after converting the number to string.

The removal of the additional decimal places is just for convenience as it is a very common situation.You can skip it if not needed.

```
// Keep only digits, hyphen  and decimal points:
             myNum.toString()   .replace(/[^-\d.]/g, "")
                // Remove duplicated decimal point, if one exists:
                .replace(/^(\d*\.)(.*)\.(.*)$/, '$1$2$3')
                // Keep only two digits past the decimal point:
                .replace(/\.(\d{2})\d+/, '.$1')
                // Add thousands separators:
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
```

Comment: OK... this is not at all what I asked for. This must only work with strings, since numbers don't have a `replace` method. And removing duplicated decimal points and keeping only 2 digits after the decimal point is irrelevant to my question.

Comment: Perhaps you could update the answer based on Elias' feedback?

Comment: that last .replace does the job for me, nice, thanks !