# How do I add a thousand seperator to a number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format numbers using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-to-format-numbers-using-javascript)

I want to add a thousand seperator, like `.`, to a number in JavaScript.

> ```
> 1000 -> 1.000
> 1000000 -> 1.000.000
> ```

What is the most elegant way to do that?

Comment: Quite some things, but none didn't really work, so I thought it's not worth inserting them here.

Comment: It's worth at least mentioning them. So that we know you tried and failed. So, what did you try? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format numbers using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-to-format-numbers-using-javascript) and [Format numbers in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript). Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 21):

I don't know about elegant...

```
function addCommas(n){
    var rx=  /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    return String(n).replace(/^\d+/, function(w){
        while(rx.test(w)){
            w= w.replace(rx, '$1,$2');
        }
        return w;
    });
}
```

addCommas('123456789456.34');

returned value: (String)  123,456,789,456.34

Answer (score 6):

Try such a Regexp:

```
function formatNumber(num)
{
    return ("" + num).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, function($1) { return $1 + "." });
}

alert(formatNumber(100000));
```

​

​
To be honest, I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254185/regular-expression-for-formatting-numbers-in-javascript), while was trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take (just for fun):

```
var num = 1000000;
var cnt = 0; // temp counter. 
var s = String(num).split('').
                    reverse().
                    map(function(v) { 
                        if (cnt < 2) {
                            cnt += 1; 
                            return v;
                        } else {
                            cnt = 0; 
                            return ',' + v;
                        }
                    }).
                    reverse().
                    join('');
// 1,000,000
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code to do the job:

```
(10000000 + "").split('').reverse().map(function (value, i) {
    return (!(i % 3)) ? "." + value : value;
}).reverse().join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to add commas, found here: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    var sep = ',';
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + sep + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

I modified the code a bit to add `var sep = ',';`, so you can change your separator easily, depending on the language.

Comment: Much thanks!  
I changed the `var sep = ','; `  to `var sep = '.';`  
 and use it like this:   `addCommas(price.toFixed(2).replace('.',','))`
to get the format like this:  `3.426,00`