# Regex for Currency in jquery fro non decimal value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
num.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
```

The above regex is not working properly.

ex-
if value= 123456789
result should be= 12,34,56,789

if value= 12345678
result should be= 1,23,45,678

if value= 123456
result should be= 1,23,456

Please suggest.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hL2pF2/1 try this link. Hope you will get the answer

Comment: @Karthik - this is for decimal as you provide. i need only for integer.

Comment: @smithIndia You can create a prototype as I mentioned in my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @smith http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254185/regular-expression-for-formatting-numbers-in-javascript check this!

Comment: please test for 232323, result should be 2,32,323, but this regex is showing 23,23,23

Comment: @Karthik- i don't need if number is 123123123 as 123,123,123 , my requirement is 12,31,23,123

Answer (score 1):

You can create a extension method as follows

```
Number.prototype.format = function(){
   return this.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
};
var num=123456789;
alert(num.format());
```

Please see the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/Lh2pjoaz/), it is working fine.

Comment: This regex is escaping one digit, so this is not working properly.

Comment: num="123456"; result= 12,456 => 3 is missing

Comment: @smithIndia No, please create the prototype function and try. It seems working fine in my end. And you can give the number itself, no need for string. For that only we have created the prototype of number.

Comment: @smithIndia Ah, my mistake sorry, I have given the regex as parameter, now I have updated it.

Comment: @SibeeshVenu- your regex is showing 123,456, but this is wrong, my requirement is 1,23,456

Comment: @SibeeshVenu- Are you looking or escape that ?

Comment: @smith India I have already left office and I may be able to help you tomorrow (Now I am using mobile). Please don't mind. Thank you.