# In React, how to format a number with commas?

Tags: reactjs

My API is sending React integers like `10, 31312, 4000`.

In my React component, what's the right way to format these numbers like so:

```
from: 10, 31312, 4000
to: 10, 31,312, 4,000
```

### Update

The number is being provided by my Rails API and rendered in a React component:

```
const RankingsList = ({rankings, currentUserId}) => {
  return (
      <div className="listGroup">
        {rankings.map((ranking, index) =>
            <span className="number">{ranking.points}</span>
        )}
      </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you getting them as JSON? Can you elaborate a little bit why, and how you will be using them ?

Comment: sorry about that, just updated w an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

### **Print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript**

You can find a general JS solution for this:

---

toLocaleString:

```
// A more complex example: 
number.toLocaleString(); // "1,234,567,890"

// A more complex example: 
var number2 = 1234.56789; // floating point example
number2.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits:2}) // "1,234.57"
```

[**NumberFormat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) (Safari not supported):

```
var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat();
nf.format(number); // "1,234,567,890"
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32154217/6200607

---

var number = 1234567890; // Example number to be converted

⚠ Mind that javascript has a maximum integer value of 9007199254740991

---

**Other Solution:**

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/comma-values-in-numbers/

> 2345643.00 will return 2,345,643.00

Comment: You link to a "CSS Solution" is just another JavaScript solution.

Comment: Thanks @mikeschuld I fixed it.

Answer (score 46):

I have a class which converts a number to either `31,312` or `31,312.00`.

The code is pretty much;

`return value.toLocaleString(navigator.language, { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });`

and

`return value.toLocaleString(navigator.language, { minimumFractionDigits: 0 });`

So you can just use `toLocaleString` for converting.

**Update**

Based on your example, it would be (assuming points is a number);

```
const RankingsList = ({rankings, currentUserId}) => {
  return (
      <div className="listGroup">
        {rankings.map((ranking, index) =>
            <span className="number">{ranking.points.toLocaleString(navigator.language, { minimumFractionDigits: 0 })}</span>
        )}
      </div>
  );
};
```

However, you might want to just move this into a smaller component called `NumberDisplay` and a property to show/hide decimal points'

Comment: Thanks Tim, in your React app, are you storing this func in some type of global helper file?

Comment: @AnApprentice We have a component named NumericDisplay, which takes in a property for NumericFormat that is either NoneFractional or Standard. In this, we then use a NumericHelper file that will return the value. So we use the component in the majority of places, but can also use the helper if we want.

Answer (score 5):

```
  export const formatNumber = inputNumber => {
    let formetedNumber=(Number(inputNumber)).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
    let splitArray=formetedNumber.split('.');
    if(splitArray.length>1){
      formetedNumber=splitArray[0];
    }
    return(formetedNumber);
  };
```

Please note that I am ignoring the decimal points

Answer (score 5):

```
const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};
```

Comment: How does this work, and what is the improvement over Vikram Kodag's `replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')`?

Comment: The regular expression uses a look-ahead to find positions within the string where the only thing to the right of it is one or more groupings of three numbers

Comment: and i answered on prespective of integers only Vikram is handling the decimals aswell because the regex i provided will return value for example if i enter the value of x=1233.3332 the output will be : 1,233.3,332 for handling decimals i have found another regex 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254185/regular-expression-for-formatting-numbers-in-javascript

in there look for the answer of @Adam Legget

Comment: Don't comment comments asking for explanation (of something not obvious from the post) or additional information: Edit [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this works perfectly for react native

Answer (score 3):

React component to format numbers in an input or as text: [react-number-format](http://s-yadav.github.io/react-number-format/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React from 'react'

export default function Test() {

    const [finalAmount, setfinalAmount]= useState("");

    const handleNumChange = (event) => {
    const str = (event.target.value).replace(/\,/g,'');
    setfinalAmount(str);
  }
  return (
    <div>
        <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleNumChange}
                    value={new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
                    }).format(finalAmount)}
                  />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this component.

```
// number cell
function NumberCell({ line, handleBlur, property, readOnly }) {
    function replaceNonNumeric(numStr) {
        return String(numStr).replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
    }
    function commarize(numStr) {
        return Number(replaceNonNumeric(numStr)).toLocaleString()
    }

   
    useEffect(() => {
        setValue(commarize(line[property.name]))
    }, [line])


    const [value, setValue] = useState(line[property.name])

    const handleChange = e => {
        setValue(commarize(e.target.value))
    }

    function proxyHandleBlur(e) {
        e.target.value = replaceNonNumeric(e.target.value)
        return handleBlur(e)
    }

    return (
        <input 
            name={property.name}
            value={ value }
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={proxyHandleBlur}
            type="text"
            readOnly={readOnly}
            />
    );
}
```