# how to automatically add commas to numbers being typed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a calculator. How do I add commas to an input, so when I type 40000 it would automatically display 40,000? (The number should still stay as 40000  in order to do the right calculation.)

This is how I get the value of the inputs:

```
 handleStateChange = (e) => {
        const { target: { name, value } } = e
        this.setState({ [name]: value })
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In React, how to format a number with commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784774/in-react-how-to-format-a-number-with-commas)

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
  const handleChange = (name, e) => {
    const { value } = e.targe;
    if(value) {
      const formattedValue = (Number(value.replace(/\D/g, '')) || '').toLocaleString();
      this.setState({ [name]: formattedValue });
    }
    return null;
  };
```

Comment: const { value } = e.target;

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex as below

```
handleStateChange = (e) => {
  const { target: { name, value } } = e
  this.setState({ [name]: value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to put comma between integer, the easiest way is using `toLocaleString()`, and you can use **regex** to remove comma from string,

### here an example.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  handleStateChange = e => {
    const {
      target: { name, value }
    } = e;
    
    const formatNumber = parseInt(value.replace(/,/g, '')).toLocaleString();
    this.setState({ [name]: formatNumber });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleStateChange} value={this.state.foo} name="foo" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

const handleChange = (e) => {
const { value } = e.target;

```
    if (value !== '') {
      const formattedValue = (Number(value.replace(/\D/g, '')) || '').toLocaleString();
      setTotalCharge(formattedValue);
    } else {
      // Handle the case when the input is empty
      setTotalCharge('');
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -1):

React Number Format
[try this npm package.](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format#readme)

Comment: If possible, you can provide code sample of how to apply the package to OP's problem to make your answer more helpful.