# Vue js - input saving a value to a variable but displaying a different one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to save the value the user enters into a variable, but display a slightly different one. For example, the user starts typing "300000" and it will be assigned to a variable, but I want to display this value to him as "3,000,000". The value will be changed every time there is a change in input. Is it possible to do this in vue.js? I tried using @change and saved the value to the other variable but I don't like this idea.

`<input type="text" :value="valueFireHome" @change="addCommas">`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784774/in-react-how-to-format-a-number-with-commas

Just make a function in the onChange prop of the input.
put in the event.target.value and modify it and set the state (I'm not sure how that works in Vue)