# Thousand Separators for NumberInput

Tags: react-admin

Need a way to deal with number format in react admin. I tried to change the format with Record Context. But my calculation went wrong.
I need something like this

5000000000 --> 5,000,000,000

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression for formatting numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254185/regular-expression-for-formatting-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions - parse / format. "Transforming Input Value to/from Record":
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#recipes

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this function to format numbers:

```
export const formatDecimals = (figure) => {
  return figure && figure.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};
```